# c++ memory allocator vptr / new implementation

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was making a memory pool allocator for a project I am working on. My pool allocator returns chunks of memory fine however my class inherits from another class.

```
    MyClass *fx = (MyClass*)pool->allocateEffect(sizeof(MyClass));
    *fx = MyClass();
```

This doesn't setup the vtable for me. I did some searching and found out the new operator can take in a chunk of memory.

```
    MyClass *fx = (MyClass*)pool->allocateEffect(sizeof(MyClass));
    fx = new(fx)MyClass();
```

And this will initialize the vptr. So I was wondering if there is anyway to allocate the vptr my self or is it strictly up to the compilers whim?

Comment: The line fx = new (fx) MyClass(); is called placement new, you can put it in your allocateEffect method and make this method a templated method to get the class for using with placement new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new(fx)MyClass()
```

This is called "placement new" and will actually *call a constructor* to actually create an object.

Until you created that object in the memory you allocated, *it simply does not exist* (as an object of that type) so it is just raw untyped memory that you cast to something, which results in undefined behavior.

I would suggest that you make your function  a template like.

```
template<class T>
T* allocateEffect() { return new (allocate_some_memory(sizeof(T))) T(); }
```

adding proper variadic templates and forwarding for constructor arguments is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was called placement new. Does this mean there is no other way to muck around with the vfptr of a block of memory? I see, really interesting. could you link to this post and ill vote it as answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

or just mention its a c++ standard

Comment: @user1659134: The vfptr is set _during the constructor_. If the constructor hasn't been called, then the object doesn't technically exist, so it's not an issue.  placement new is just a way of calling the constructor at a preallocated location in memory.

Comment: forwarding constructor arguments + exception safety http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b408eafc1b96c92a

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks I did roughly the same thing earlier today